# Unable to access router's configuration page (192.168.1.1)

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, wireless-networking, router

The router is a TP-LINK TD-W8951ND.

I tried to access the configuration page through Wi-Fi and through wired connection both didn't work. I tried restarting (the problem has been persisting for a while actually) i also tried using a different browser and different computers but all without luck.

The default gateway is 192.168.1.1 and the ping works well. I can't seem to figure out. Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

[image: Diagnosis Result]

Comment: You've checked the connection with `ping`, but have you done the other suggested checks (proxy/firewall and diagnostics)?

Comment: I don't know how to do that to be honest

Comment: Did you do *any* initial configuration already?  In other words, something that may have changed the router's access method?  If not, you are simply trying `http://192.168.1.1/` in your web browser, correct?

Comment: The suggestions appear to be links, so click on them and take it from there.

Comment: @Run5k i didn't do any initial configuration

Comment: @AmineBirouk, do you have any security software (i.e. antivirus, firewall, etc.) installed?

Comment: @AFH I don't use proxy and chrome is white-listed on the firewall, the result of the diagnosis i included in Edit 1

Comment: I would try resetting the router to factory defaults, then see if you can access it via a hardwired Ethernet connection:  http://www.tp-link.co.th/faq-140.html

Comment: @YisroelTech I have windows default defender, and Malwarebytes although the problem was there before i installed Malwarebytes, and the configuration page is inaccessible from my smartphone aswell

Comment: @Run5k I am afraid that if i reset it and the problem persists, i won't be able to reconfigure it again.

Comment: @AmineBirouk - If you haven't done any initial configuration yet, you won't lose any of your settings and you don't want to continue utilizing a router that you can't manage.

Comment: It has all the elements of a firewall problem. Try disabling your firewall. If you're worried about doing this, remove the WAN connection from your router while the firewall is off.

Comment: Try `https://192.168.1.1/` or `http://192.168.1.1:8080/` or `https://192.168.1.1:8080/`. You may want to scan routers IP with [Advanced IP scanner](http://www.advanced-ip-scanner.com/) or from [fing](https://www.fing.io/) (that can work on PC or phones)  to figure out what port was set instead of default 80. I afraid somebody already changed many settings on it, so probably your next problem would be non default password then the quickest way will be as already suggested - reset it

Comment: @AmineBirouk, have you made any progress?

Comment: @Run5k tried everything that has been mentioned here none of it seemed to work, even resetting/

Comment: If you did a factory reset and still can't get to the router's management web page from multiple computers and browsers, it actually sounds like something might be wrong with the router itself.  Did you buy this brand-new?

Comment: @Run5k No i have it for years now, well it is what it is i'll just use it until it dies

Comment: If that's the case, it may have developed some minor issues after years of faithful service.  Sorry that we couldn't help out a bit more.

Comment: @Run5k thanks for your time, it has been appreciated

Comment: Always glad to help, and best of luck in the future.

Comment: one thing worth checking is your proxy settings. For some reason my windows machine either turned the proxy on or unchecked the box saying not to use it on LAN, and that was the cause of the issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem and accidentally found the solution for it. This is how I solved my problem to view router home page.

First in windows go to `control panel> Network and internet`

[image]

from the `Network and Sharing Centre` go to `View network computers and devices` inside that window you can see your router device. Using third mouse key open menu in your router device icon and select first option `View device webpage`. It should open `192.168.1.1:xxxxxx` page with your router home page. I am guessing that `192.168.1.1` requires certain port to open the router home page.

Comment: thanks for the answer @Eka, do you know where to look in MAC for the same?

Answer (score 2):

It’s probably because the router firewall is enabled and prevents the other devices to connect to it. In this case you have to reset the router (by pushing the reset button with a pin or power off then power on after about 15 seconds). When the router comes up, you can access the admin page only for about one minute. In this period, you have to login the admin page, open the firewall tab, check the disabled radio button and save the new setting. Perhaps you have to do this procedure more than one time, because the connection may be lost sooner than you can change the firewall setting. During connecting to the admin page, you have to refresh the http://192.168.1.1 address page (by pressing F5) again and again to be loaded.
After you have changed the firewall setting, the router admin page will be accessible in a normal way.

Comment: Do you have two accounts with similar names?  They should be merged if so.  Please see help centre for assistance

Answer (score 1):

I recently observed the same symptoms, and my solution isn't listed here, so in case this helps someone...

When trying to load the router's configuration page, I saw ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED in Chrome, I could load all other pages from the internet, I could ping the router's IP, I could log in to the router's configuration page from other computers.

In my case, I had some other virtual networks set-up on this PC from Oracle's VirtualBox (using Vagrant scripting). These were set-up to allow local development servers to be accessible from the real network, and were likely routing the local traffic to a virtual local server for some IP addresses (like the router/gateway).

**My fix was to open Window's "Network Connections" page, and disable those added virtual networks.** The router's config page was able to load immediately after.

PS: I've not had this trouble with VirtualBox/Vagrant before, so I'm sure one of the guest/host IP domains/ranges in one of the virtual servers were in conflict this time. This laptop moves to different networks, so the IP domains change often.

Comment: Thanks, it helped me with VMware

Answer (score 0):

It seams you are not the only one who experienced this problem with this router.

http://forum.tp-link.com/showthread.php?3790-TD-W8961ND-cant-access-router-login-page

Router has some memory problems - probably low memory after some time and can't handle web requests. Suggestion is to disable UPnP in router. UPnP service is memory hungry and disabling your modem could have enough resources for web requests.

Answer (score 0):

If it is one of those lovely TP-Link bugs, then all bets are off. However, try some basic troubleshooting first:

- Disconnect the WAN-side cable (phone line or ethernet, assuming it is either of these).
- Also applies to LAN-side access: Make sure you access it with ethernet cable and isolate the router to just the one ethernet cable and client PC that you're trying to access the config page with.
- Do all this before booting the router to make sure the boot is 'clean'.
  Do you see the same issue?

If not, it suggests that something is interfering when other connections (WAN, LAN, WiFi) are plugged-in/active.

This may be at worst, a specific attacker, or otherwise anything of: some buggy process on any connected device, or some network connection type (overloading, bug, etc).
As suggested, the router running out of RAM (and a bug in handling this condition) is a common problem, especially under heavy load.

Also, check that there isn't some sort of firewall setting on the router (or even your PC) blocking your client IP from accessing the web interface. Some routers support this.

**I would strongly suggest to *always* disable uPnP** as **mligor** has suggested. 
It is way too much of a security risk and if you need to open ports instead of uPnP's automated method, do it manually and learn what this entails.
Also, disable remote administration *and* set a strong admin password.

Answer (score 0):

Reset the router to it's factory defaults as described in the Users manual. There is no good reason you shouldn't be able to reach the (web) configuration. If your first attempt to reset to factory defaults fails, *do* try again. These things are not precision devices, and can fail quite miserably. It may take *several* attempts to bring it to Factory Default. In case you're also wondering; Windows will *not* attempt to block you're ability to connect to your router **unless** of course **you've** made additional changes to the defaults in the windows firewall.

Lastly, even as obvious as this may seem. **Do** check that the network cable(s) are *firmly* inserted, and the ports indicate they're active (light and, or blinking).

Answer (score -1):

You can set IP manually also.

1. like IP: 192.168.0.2
2. Mask: 255.255.255.0
3. Gateway: 192.168.0.1
4. Then go to browser and go to url: 192.168.0.1