# Cant access my router web page even tho i am connected to it and can ping to it

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I've looked many places for answers yet i was unable to find one.

The problem: I own a Mikrotik hAP lite router and want to access the router web page.

I can ping on default gateway (192.168.1.254)

I tried:

1. Acessing it with the help of Mikrotik official docs https://help.mikrotik.com/docs/display/UM/hAP+lite+TC didn't work
2. [Unable to access router's configuration page (192.168.1.1)](https://superuser.com/questions/1176361/unable-to-access-routers-configuration-page-192-168-1-1) i tried the stuff suggested here
3. Accessing it via Mikrotik mobile app (says that router refuses access)
4. Pretty much everything except factory reset.

I dont want to factory reset it because I am little sceptical. We had an IT guy configure it for us and I dont think i have the skills to put it back if I do.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What happens when you try to access it? What address are you using?

Comment: Maybe that same IT guy configured it not to allow web access? It's certainly possible to set that up

Comment: @Tetsujin I am using the default gateway(192.168.1.254), tried even the 192.168.88.1 in the web in both situations it says that the website is unavailable. In the mikrotik app i tried connecting via MAC and it told me router refused connection

Comment: @YisroelTech It even refuses to connect from the official mikrotik app so idk.

Comment: Microtik app is not special with some kind of backdoor, it can be blocked in the same way typical web access is blocked. So given that you know that some IT guy configured it - and apparently you can't ask him about he accessed it or if he configured something for the access - I think that is the most probable issue here.

Comment: *Acessing it with the help of Mikrotik official docs* ... including `winbox`?

Comment: Are you trying to access it wirelessly? Elementary security is to allow hard-wired ethernet only.

Comment: @JaromandaX yes I even tried winbox

Comment: @Tetsujin yes I tried accessing it wirelessly with my phone and my laptop

Comment: Next step is to wire up then. My own router cannot be accessed wirelessly. It's a simple security feature; means someone has to be physically in the building & wired to your own ethernet - it can't be hacked by anyone 'outside'.

Comment: @Tetsujin also tried connecting via ethernet cable in the first port on the router, still refuses connection.

Comment: Then I'm out of ideas, sorry.

Comment: @Tetsujin - documentation implies (or did I infer?) that setup can ONLY be done wirelessly!!! seems odd, so maybe I read it wrong